# Adding a fade across transition to addClass for background image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, navigation, click, fade

I am using jQuery to add and remove a class to/from my nav links which changes the background image.  You can see this in action on [this page](http://nickputman.com/test/).

I would like, if possible, to add a fade transition between the images, ideally without one fading out completely and the other fading in (so presumably fading one image over the other so that it obscures the image completely).

I am not sure how to do this with jQuery though, and would be grateful for any advice.  Here is an example of a click function as it currently looks:

```
$("nav").delegate("a.fade", "click", function ()
    {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Offtopic ... Add body overflow-y : scroll; (a design elementary) to prevent page 'shakes' (when you call the contact form).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#panel').animate({ opacity: '-=0.5' }, 200);
```

Use the jQuery.animate function. From my example #panel's opacity (starting at 1) will decrease to 0.5 over 200 milliseconds.

Do this for both #panel and #contact. You can play around with the timing so that they animate the way you want.

```
$('object').animate({property: target value (-/+)}, timespan);
```

You could also do check on the #panel opacity value to start the #contact animation.

if #panel.opacity < 0.8 
then #contact.animate...

Comment: I am happy with the sliding contact form, i.e. panel div.  What I am looking for is a fade transition on the nav links, i.e. the leaves.  At the moment I am adding and removing a class "current" which changes the background image.  I am hoping to be able to change this to a fading transition.